# Array in C struct, pointer to constant

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;
} person;


int main(){
    person Peter = {"peter", 19};
    person Petercp = Peter;
    Peter.name[0] = 'a';
    Petercp.name = "hello";
    printf("%s %d\n", Peter.name, Peter.age);
    printf("%s %d\n", Petercp.name, Petercp.age);
}
```

the compiler gives me the error message of "BAD ACCESS" for the line

```
Peter.name[0] = 'a'
```

but the following line seems good

```
Petercp.name = "hello";
```

It seems as if the array of person.name is a pointer to constant. Am I right to make the conclusion?

And, if I declare the array inside the struct to be

```
char name[];
```

I am again allowed to make the change for

```
Peter.name[0] = 'a'
```

Why is that?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `person Peter = {"peter", 19};`, you point `name` to a string literal "peter".

`Peter.name[0] = 'a'` tries to change the 1. element in what `name` is pointing to. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior and in your case it causes a crash. In practice string literals are often loaded in a read only section of memory.

On the other hand doing `Petercp.name = "hello";` just changes the pointer to point somewhere else, which is fine.

If you declare the name member as `char name[64]` then the initializer

```
  person Peter = {"peter", 19};
```

will copy the string "peter" into the `name` array. The name array is just an ordinary char array where you can change the individual elements.

Comment: "`person Peter = {"peter", 19};`
will copy the string "peter" into the name array." This works in c?

Comment: @Zaibis yes, it does. It's similar to doing e.g. `char buf[64] = "peter";`

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't declared any space for peter, so Peter.name[0] doesn't exist.

When you do the initial assignment using a constant string the compiler is assigning the constant string value to that, and you can't change constants.

The following would work:

```
int main(){
    person Peter;
    Peter.age = 19;
    Peter.name = calloc(sizeof(*(Peter.name)),sizeof("hello")+1);
    strncpy(Peter.name,"hello",sizeof("hello"));
    Peter.name[0] = 'a';
    printf("%s %d\n", Peter.name, Peter.age);
    free(Peter.name);
}
```

The difference here is that a straight `Peter.name = "hello"` make `Peter.name` point directly to the (const) string literal. 
`strncpy` by comparison will copy from that literal to the space put aside by the `calloc`

Comment: does strncpy change Peter.name as a pointer to a string literal to a pointer to a normal array?

Comment: @user2362322 strncpy copies Byte by Byte from source the chars into the destination memory area.

Comment: Great, I get what you mean. By using the function malloc, Peter.name now is a pointer variable pointing to a mutable array, where the manipulation of the char inside is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a name by `"NAME"` creates a string literal which is defined as constant. 
So you aren't allowed to change anything on the address, where `name` is pointing to.

Its in c11 under 6.7.3

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

```
Peter.name[0] = 'a'
```

And thats exactly what your trying to do in this line.

So you would break your code. But the compiler fortunately avoids this.